# Sorting divs in grid format using only CSS

Tags: css, html

I have a problem in sorting the div(s), i have two types `a, b`

```
a - should always be at the front (all a types)
b - should be following all a types.
```

HTML:

```
<div class="" style="">
    <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="a">a</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a, .b {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  padding:15px;
  margin:5px;
}

.a {
  float:left;
  background-color: blue;
}

.b { background-color: red; }
```

This seems to work fine in a line:

[image: works fine as line]

But breaks as a grid:

[image: problme]

Desired result (number of boxes is irrelevant):

[image: result]

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kQkn9/

How would i go about fixing this problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: @woz Updated answer, maybe you can understand now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for a pure CSS solution, your only option is to use Flexbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/kQkn9/2/

```
.container { /* parent element */
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.a, .b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.a {
  background-color: blue;
}

.b {
  -webkit-flex-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  order: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Browser support: Chrome, Opera, IE10.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: THAT is a super cool solution.  bummer the browser support isn't better

Answer (score 1):

don't believe this is possible with CSS and HTML alone.  My recommendation would be to sort the a's and b's, without changing your css as you have it then re-insert them into the DOM in their new, sorted order.

something to this effect: (in JQ)

```
var listOfAs = $('.a').clone(); 
var listOfBs = $('.b').clone(); 
var parent = $('.a').first().parent('div'); 
$('.a, .b').remove(); 
parent.append(listOfAs); 
parent.append(listOfBs);
```

I know this is a touch cumbersome and not super 'responsive' but as i said, don't think its possible with CSS alone...this is just a quick-and-dirty implementation to get you started.

PS: updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kQkn9/6/

EDIT: clearly this IS possible in newer browsers (thanks to @cimmanon).  If you need to support older browsers, you'll have to do something like this (which is definitely less cool)